# Symfony 2.3: «Bad credentials» on different browsers and different Firefox profiles (except one)

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-user-bundle

I was doing debugging on a different profile (called "Debugging") on Iceweasel (Firefox on Debian Linux) and other one called "Entertainment" (and Google Chrome too), and for my surprise I can't login on none of these, but I still can on the usual profile (called "Development").

I tried activating the admin user, with no success. It's the same with develop and production environments, and there's no error message in the Symfony or Apache logs.

Symfony 2.3.9
SonataUserBundle 2.2.3
FOSUserBundle 1.3.3

Comment: did you try to clear cache for all you needed environments and also may be apc?

Comment: Yes, I always do it. Not just the usual `php app/console cache:clear` also `rm -rfv app/cache/dev/*` and `rm -rfv app/cache/prod/*`, just to be sure. About APC, I have no idea. I'll give a check.

The big question is why is giving me problems with other Firefox profiles, and other browsers?.

Comment: what about cache folders for Debugging and Entertainment environments?  look at app/cache/ folder

Comment: I cleared the Google chrome cache and the Firefox cache (for every profile). And the result is the same, I can login in the Development profile, but not in the other two (Entertainment and Debugging). The same thing with Chrome.

I'm gonna check the APC config.

Comment: The APC cache option is disabled (the only entry is in `config_prod.yml` and all the lines are commented. Any other idea?

Comment: This is kind of strange: if I try with `php app/console fos:user:deactivate admin` every browser on every profile tells me `the account is disabled.`, if I run `php app/console fos:user:activate admin` the same issue returns as usual: `bad credentials`.

Comment: paste your security config

Answer (score 0):

Well, this embarrassing, the cause of the "strange" error wasn't other than a... wrong password! in other words, just a "bad credential".

I really don't know what password was stored in database for the admin user, I never typed it in the "Developer" Iceweasel profile login form, but I always did it in the other profiles (even in Google Chrome), so that explain everything. Resetting the admin password in the console "fixed" the issue.